# chroot permission denied! But I'm root!

Tags: permissions, password, chroot

I am trying to chroot into an old HD to change a forgotten password, 
but chroot says permission denied? what gives? I am root! The harddrive I am trying to chroot into is an old version of edUbuntu 7.10 might that have anything to do with it?

```
root@h:~# chroot /media/usb0/
chroot: failed to run command `/bin/bash': Permission denied
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -la /media/`?

Comment: Also, what is the output of the full command: `chroot /media/usb0 /bin/bash`?  Lastly, are you sure the usb is mounted at `/media`

Comment: And I'd like `ls -l /media/usb0/bin/bash` and `grep /media /proc/mounts`

Comment: Please post the output of `mount | grep /media/usb0` as well.

Comment: Why `chroot`? Can't you just delete the entry in `/etc/shadow`, boot, login as root and set a password?

Comment: chroot because I have various rootly tasks to do. the cd drive is whack on  mt old laptop, and it wont boot via live usb. so that's why im using it as an external hd

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Chroot in ubuntu or recovering Ubuntu,Debian Linux

boot from livecd of ubuntu, if you installed with system 32bit use 32bit Live CD, If 64bit use 64 bit live cd.

Mount the Linux Partitions using

```
# sudo blkid
```

Output:

```
sysadmin@localhost:~$ sudo blkid
[sudo] password for sysadmin: 
/dev/sda1: UUID="846589d1-af7a-498f-91de-9da0b18eb54b" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="36e2f219-da45-40c5-b340-9dbe3cd89bc2" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="f1d4104e-22fd-4b06-89cb-8e9129134992" TYPE="ext4"
```

Here my / Partition is /dev/sda6

Mount the / Partition to mount point using

```
# sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt
```

Then Mount the linux access points, Linux devices, Proc, sys

Linux Device

```
# sudo mount --bind /dev/ /mnt/dev
```

proc system information

```
# sudo mount --bind /proc/ /mnt/proc
```

Kernel information to user space

```
# sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
```

If we need to enable the networking we need to do the following steps (Optional).

```
# cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf
```

Change the Linux root to be the device we mounted earlier in step 2

```
# sudo chroot /mnt
```

Now try to change the root password it will work.

Comment: Once I remounted the device under root, I was able to chroot in without issues! Thanks for the tips here!

Answer (score 10):

You can't execute */bin/bash* in your chroot and that is most likely because your filesystem is mount with the *noexec* option and maybe also with *nosuid*. You can check this running with the mount command as that will show the mount options and you may need to remount the filesystem with other options.

Answer (score 2):

(this does not answer the chroot, but can allow you to change a forgotten *unix* passwd)

I understood disk is mounted on /media/usb

try

```
cd /media/usb/etc
vi shadow
```

pick line with root, wipe second field (or you can pick the crypted string of a know password from your actual /etc/shadow).

- in case shadow don't exists, do the same in passwd